# Is to iterate through a jTable and pass column values to an sql query in java

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

I have a jTable with 4 columns and 6 rows. i want to iterate thru the rows picking up the values of column index0 which is my ID column and passing it to a count sql query. i have written the below code which is not working because i haven't figured out how to pass the columns values after iterating through the table.

can someone please let me know what am doing wrong on my code please.

```
for (int row = 0; row > jTable2.getRowCount(); row++){
        for (int col =0; col > jTable2.getColumnCount(); col ++)
        try{
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable2.getModel();
            String selected = model.getValueAt(row, col+1).toString();
            String sql = "select COUNT(COURSEBOOKED) from APP.BOOKCOURSE where COURSEBOOKED = '"+selected+"'"; 
            try(Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:MTD","herbert","elsie1*#");
                PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);) {
                    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    while(rs.next()){
                        String Sum = rs.getString("COUNT(COURSEBOOKED)");
                        System.out.println(Sum);
                        if (rs.wasNull()){
                            System.out.println("No record found");
                        }
                    }
            }
            catch(SQLException e){
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
```

This is the final code that came up with after the changes.

```
        String sql = "select COUNT(COURSEBOOKED) as count from APP.BOOKCOURSE where COURSEBOOKED =?";
    try(Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:MTD","herbert","elsie1*#");
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);){
                 for(int row = 0; row < jTable2.getRowCount(); row++){
                        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable2.getModel();
                        String selected = model.getValueAt(row, 1).toString();
                        pst.setString(1, selected);
                        try(ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();){
                             while (rs.next()){
                                String Sum = rs.getString("count");
                                System.out.println(Sum);
                             }
                        }
                    }
                }
    catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
    }
```

Which brings me to my next question. AM not sure whether i should start a new thread for it or continue on this one. My challenge is that i now want to append an addition column to the existing 4 columns on the current jTable2 and display the values of the above query. to add a new column i have used this code,

```
TableColumn c = new TableColumn();
c.setHeaderValue("Training accomplished");
model.addColumn(c);
```

This adds the column but populates its with values from column index0. how do i get the new added column to be populated by the values held in Sum from the query above.

Comment: It's not working mainly because your for loops are wrong. `row` will never be `> jTable2.getRowCount()`. same for `col`. And columns start at 0, not at 1. You should also learn to use prepared statements correctly. The whole point of them is to pass parameters and avoid string concatenation to pass them. Finally, stop catching exceptions and ignoring them. You're shooting yourself in the foot by doing that: if an exception is thrown, you won't know it.

Comment: `select COUNT(COURSEBOOKED) as summedValue ...` then you'd be able to use `rs.getString("summedValue")` instead.  I think you'll find that the database is assigning it's own "name" for the column, which doesn't match yours (as a guess)

Comment: 1. Why are you using 2nd for loop (which iterates on cells) when you only need cell with index 0? also, your terminating conditions for both the loops are wrong as already told by JB. You should use `<` in place `>`.
2. As JB has already said, use prepared statement. Google it.
3. Why are you creating a new connection everytime you need to fire a query? Very in-efficient.
4. Use an alias in your query as stated by MadProgrammer. It will help you in getting the result.

Comment: You should start a fresh question for new problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like below. Note that I haven't tested this code so far, so you might need to debug it. Also check the comments on your question.

```
String sql = "select COUNT(COURSEBOOKED) as count from APP.BOOKCOURSE where COURSEBOOKED = ?"; 
try(
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:MTD","herbert","elsie1*#");
   PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);){
   for (int row = 0; row < jTable2.getRowCount(); row++){
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable2.getModel();
        String selected = model.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
        pst.setString(1, selected);            
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            String Sum = rs.getString("count");
            System.out.println(Sum);
            if (rs.wasNull()){
                System.out.println("No record found");
            }
        }
    }
}
catch(SQLException e){
}
catch(Exception e){
}
```

Comment: At a minimum, the code you post in an answer should compile... Have a downvote.

Comment: With pleasure @hd1 :P

Comment: Now wait a minute. We have try-with-resources as a feature now. Do you know that? It has been with us for quite some time now. Also, you have edited the code. Maybe you could have formatted the code if you had any problem with that.

Comment: Thank you guys your recommendations worked like a charm . Your  propose code @Aakash works wit some minor tweeks

Comment: Please select it as answer if this solved your problem.